# compress dicom files to be sent to a remote server

Tags: image, compression, dicom, bzip2, dcmtk

I'm looking for a way to compress dicom files and send them to a remote server (nodejs in my case)

I tried bz2 compression and it seems to work very well on large dicom files (tested it with 10 Mb file which gave me a 5Mb compressed file).

When it comes to small size (like a 250Kb file ), I get a size reduced by a very few kb (5 to 10 kb in most cases) which it won't be worth it

can someone please explain me why bz2 is working very well with large dicom files and  is there a better  way to compress dicom files that I can use in order to send them via internet.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to transfer the files via internet? DICOM C-STORE or a proprietary protocol? What kind of images are you talking about? Color/Grayscale, Resolution?

Comment: thank's for the reply , a transfer with  http post , I'm not sure about the dicom kind , isn't there an adaptive lossless compression method that will work  for any   kind (?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compress a DICOM dataset with images, recommendation is to use one of the compression types supported by DICOM Standard. This includes lossy and lossless JPEG, JPEG 2000, JPEG-LS, and RLE to name a few. Standard also supports encoding extended grayscale (12-16 bit grayscale) using the standard based compression techniques.

The Transfer Syntax element (0002, 0010) will indicate whether image in the DICOM dataset is already compressed or not. As for example, recompressing an already compressed image is going to appear having less compression ratio compared to the original. So the best way to measure is to compare with the original uncompressed image. If your original image is already compressed, you can calculate the uncompressed image size using (Rows x Columns x Bits Allocated / 8 x Sample Per Pixel x Number of Frames). Also, the compression ratio will vary based on the image type (color vs grayscale) and compression technique used. Typically, you will get much better compression when dealing with true color image vs a grayscale image such as an X-RAY.

As for using HTTP for uploading the file, you can also use DICOM standard defined service such as DICOMWeb (STOW-RS) REST service.

I work for LEAD Technologies and if you want to test various compressions on your DICOM files, we have a demo exe (Transfer Syntax) that ships with our free 60 day evaluation SDK that you can use for testing. Also, there is a demo for testing the DICOMWeb REST services. You can download the evaluation copy from our web site.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one solution that perfectly fits all...

**BZ2** is based on the principle that "colours" (or gray values, but I will use "colours" in this explanation) which frequently occur in the image are encoded with less bits than colours which are rare. Thus, as a rule of thumb: the bigger the image the better the compression ratio.

**JPEG** is a different approach which decomposes the image into tiles and optimizes the encoding for each tile. Thus the compression ratio is less dependent on the image size than it is for BZ2. JPEG comes in different flavors (lossy, lossless, JPEG 2000 which can create different serializations of the compressed data for different purposes, e.g. progressive refinement).

Less popular compression algorithms which are valid in DICOM but not widely supported by DICOM products are:

**RLE** (Run Length Encoding) - the pixel data is described by pairs of colour and number of pixels, so it compresses very well when you have large homogenous areas in the image. In all other cases it is rather increasing the size of the "compressed" image

**JPEG-LS** - I do not know how it is working internally, but it provides a lossless algorithm and a lossy algorithm in which you can control the loss of information (maximum difference of a pixel value after compression to the original pixel value). It is said to achieve better ratios than traditional JPEG, but as it is not widely supported, I have not used it in practice yet.

If you do not want to select the compression algorithm depending on the image type, JPEG-Lossless is probably a good compromise for you. In typical medical images, it achieves an average compression ratio of roughly 1:, a bit more with JPEG-2000.

Comment: JPEG-Lossless achieves about 1:2 sometimes 1:3 compression ratio for most cases.  With medical images, JPEG-Lossless is quite common, whereas JPEG-LS and JPEG-2000 are not.